# Round down the nearest integer power of a float

Tags: c++, qt, zooming

Given two floating point values `zoomAmount` and `zoomFactor`, I need to calculate a `newZoomAmount` such that:

```
(newZoomAmount <= zoomAmount) && (newZoomAmount == pow( zoomFactor, i ))
```

for any integer `i`. I can easily loop through the values or binary search through a table to find the answer. However: is there a closed form to accomplish this?

---

**Motivation**: The `zoomFactor` is 2<sup>⅕</sup> ≅ `1.148698354997035`, so that each 5 "zoom in" events result in ~exactly a power of two increase. When zooming a diagram to fit on screen I want the zoom level to be one of these notches so that zooming out eventually lands exactly on the 'base' 1.0 zoom level.

Comment: Tagged with Qt because this is being used to zoom a `QGraphicsView` and as such I have available any Qt methods that may allow this to be accomplished more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denoting:

```
A = zoomAmount
F = zoomFactor
newA = newZoomAmount
```

we have:

```
newA = pow(F, i)
=> log(newA) = i*log(F)
=> i = log(newA)/log(F)
```

and as newA <= A, and log is non-decreasing,

```
i = floor(log(A)/log(F))
```

---

```c
newZoomAmount = pow( zoomFactor, floor( log(zoomAmount)/log(zoomFactor) ) );
```

Comment: You got it. I edited your answer with a summary line expanding back to the values from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, logarithms.  I'll ignore the fact that the underlying implementation of `log` probably iterates because you probably don't mind.

Using the following:

```
zoomFactor = 21/5
           = 1.148698354997035
zoomAmount = 2.25
```

You need to find the following (note that I use less than instead of less than or equal, see end for why):

```
(newZoomAmount < 2.25) && (newZoomAmount == 2i/5)
```

By inspection, we know (since `zoomFactor5 == 2` and `zoomFactor6 == 2.297... > 2.25`)

```
newZoomAmount == 2
i == 5
```

So, to get the current `zoomAmount` in terms of an exponent, we take:

```
zoomExponent = log(zoomAmount) / log(zoomFactor)
             = 0.81093... / 0.13862...
             = 5.84962...
```

To get the next lowest integer, you should subtract 1, then take the ceiling.

```
newZoomExponent = ⌈zoomExponent - 1⌉
                = ⌈4.84962...⌉
                = 5
```

Finally:

```
newZoomAmount = zoomFactornewZoomExponent
```

The reason we use the ceiling of the decrement instead of just the floor is to handle the special case where `zoomAmount` is a perfect power of `zoomFactor`, in which case

```
⌊zoomExponent⌋ == zoomExponent
newZoomAmount == zoomAmount
```

Which we obviously don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute and re-evaluate:

`(newZoomAmount <= zoomAmount) && (newZoomAmount == pow( zoomFactor, i ))` => `pow( zoomFactor, i ) <= zoomAmount` => `i * ln(zoomFactor) <= ln(zoomAmount)` => `i <= ln(zoomAmount) / ln(zoomFactor)` which may or may not be faster than just iterating.

Then just assign `newZoomAmount = pow( zoomFactor, i );`

Comment: +1 for the subtitution and recalculationg. Needs a `floor()` to turn `i<=...` into `i=...`, but a very simple derivation. Embarrassed that I didn't think to do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
exponent=log(zoomAmount)/log(zoomFactor); /* zoomFactor^exponent == zoomAmount */
newZoomAmount=pow(zoomFactor,floor(exponent)); /* round down exponent */
```